# How to split data of different types in a row into separate columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking to split data of different types which are within the same column into seperate columns using pandas.
I have the below data

```
ID;Number;position
123;97529;30
123;234390;30
123;9034;1
456;90273;3028
```

My ultimate goal is to print plots such that there is a separate plots for 123 & 456. I am able to print all of them on the same plot, but am unable to split up the data for separate plotting.

Comment: There is no different data types in the same columns for the example you are giving. Can you rephrase your question, or give another more useful example? Also, if you give an example of the output you are expecting would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can iterate over the unique values in `ID`, filter the dataframe to hold only records with such an `ID` and plot -

```
for value in df['ID'].unique():
    df.loc[df['ID']==value].plot(...)
```

Comment: Oh yes ! wasnt aware of this functionality! thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
df[['ID', 'Number', 'position']] = df['ID;Number;position'].str.split(';',expand=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Output**:
{'123': [('97529', '30'), ('234390', '30'), ('9034', '1')], '456': [('90273', '3028')]}

**Code**:

```
import sys
import csv

def main():
    data={}
    with open("filename.txt", "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";")
        for id,number,position in reader:
            if id == 'ID':
                continue
            if not id in data:
                data[id] = []
            data[id].append((number, position))

    print(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```